# Как запустить новый класс из listview в нужном мне framelayout?

Tags: android-fragment, android, activity

Из listview, хочу каждый имеющийся класс запускать не отдельным окном, а во framelayout.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="134dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ListView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/framelayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Listview список,я хочу все новые активити классы запускать во FrameLayout по id. 
Как с фрагментами, я разобралась, но у меня FragmentActivity.

Comment: собственно зачем?
мне кажется лучше заменить на фрагменты

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не возможно реализовать. Android работает с Activity по принципу стека. Каждая следующая, вызываемая, ложиться поверх текущей перекрывая ее. Одновременно две Activity не могут быть активными. И невозможно сделать одну Activity составной частью другой. Для ваших целей и были придуманы Fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:
Берем весь Activity и переделываем во FragmentActivity, делаем в нем 2 фрагмента - в одном будет ListView (ну или сразу ListFragment делаем и не паримся), а в другом FrameLayout (ну или что там нужно).